# Inequality of positive integers

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have to prove the following inequalities for positive integer $n$:
$$n^n\geqslant\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^{n+1}$$
$$  2^ {n(n+1)}> (n+1)^{n+1} \left(\frac{n}{1}\right)^{n} \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^{n-1}...\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{2} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$  I tried using weighted $AM > GM > HM $ for $ (n+1), \left(\frac{n}{1}\right), \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right),...\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right), \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ . Any sort of hint/help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have solved this question, but how does it help here if you can please elaborate?

Comment: In the inequality $a^ab^b\geqslant\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^{a+b}$, if you take $a=n$ and $b=1$, it becomes $n^n\geqslant\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Could you provide a hint for 2nd one?

Comment: You shall find an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1569236/446262).